# postgresql how to group by and then get the first_time and the last_time,

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

```
event     event_time           arrival_time
7333 | 2018-09-09       | 2018-10-09
7444 | 2018-09-10       | 2018-11-09
7333 | 2018-09-11       | 2018-09-09
7555 | 2018-09-12       | 2018-08-09
7555 | 2018-09-13       | 2018-06-09
7333 | 2018-09-15       | 2018-09-09
```

then I want get the result, in my mind, we want to get the group，then every group show the first event time and the last event time

```
event event_first       arrival_first      event_last     arrival_last
7333 | 2018-09-09       | 2018-08-09       | 2018-09-15  |2018-10-09
7444 | 2018-09-10       | 2018-11-09       | 2018-09-10  |2018-11-09
7555 | 2018-09-12       | 2018-06-09       | 2018-09-13  |2018-08-09
```

had try this command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (event)
        event, event_time as event_first, event_time as event_last, arrival_time as arrival_first, arrival_time as arrvial_last
FROM   A
ORDER  BY event, event_first, event_last DESC, arrival_first, arrvial_last DESC
```

but it can not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `min` get first day and `max` get last day function.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   event int,
   event_time timestamp,
   arrival_time timestamp
);


insert into a values (7333,'2018-09-09','2018-10-09');
insert into a values (7444,'2018-09-10','2018-11-09');
insert into a values (7333,'2018-09-11','2018-09-09');
insert into a values (7555,'2018-09-12','2018-08-09');
insert into a values (7555,'2018-09-13','2018-06-09');
insert into a values (7333,'2018-09-15','2018-09-09');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT event,
    min(event_time) event_first,
    min(arrival_time) arrival_first,
    max(event_time) event_last,  
    max(arrival_time) arrival_last      
FROM A
group by event
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d44b/1/0)**:

```
| event |          event_first |        arrival_first |           event_last |         arrival_last |
|-------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  7444 | 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-09T00:00:00Z |
|  7333 | 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-10-09T00:00:00Z |
|  7555 | 2018-09-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-06-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-13T00:00:00Z | 2018-08-09T00:00:00Z |
```